# Should Post and Comment be in the Post Aggregate or should they be aggregates of their own?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, repository, blogs, aggregate

Consider the typical blog with objects `Post` and `Comment`.

For a DDD demo example i have been building i have (till now) found that both the entities `Post` and `Comment` have been appropriate for the same aggregate- the `Post` aggregate. But now i'm not so sure..

In my controllers i am finding, like you would expect, that i need to add and remove `Comments` from `Posts`. With my current model i am not tracking the identity of a `Comment` globally (like the Blue Book suggests). You you might expect that my action to delete a `Comment` may look like this:

```
public ActionResult DeleteComment(int postID, int commentID)
```

Obviously i need the `Post`'s id to retrieve it from the repository and the identifier for the particular `Comment` on that `Post` that i want to delete.

My problem is the body of the `DeleteComment(` action:

Is it ok to traverse the `Post` with a query mechanism to get the `Comment` for deletion? like this:

```
var comment = this._postRepo.WithID(postID).Comments
    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == commentID);
this._postRepo.Delete(comment);
return RedirectToAction("detail", new { id = postID });
```

..or should i be selecting the `Comment` from the repo similar to this?:

```
var comment = this._postRepo.CommentWithID(commentID)
```

..or:

```
var comment = this._postRepo.CommentWithID(postID, commentID)
```

The two above examples might seem a little silly since i shouldn't need the `Post` ID if i can track the `Comment` globally. But then if i'm tracking the `Comment` globally, shouldn't it have it's own aggregate and then is that right when `Post` and `Comment` seem to go together?

Comment: I think that Post and Comment are different aggregates. You may want to query comments across all posts, for instance. This morning Ayende Rahien (RavenDB author) did a webinar on document databases with the Post/Comment model and he made them separate roots but had a denormalized query for displaying a single post with it's comments. Granted the RavenDB website shows a similar model with everything under Post. I suppose where you put it really depends on what you want to do with the model.

Comment: @Ryan Agreed. And i'm feeling that it will need to move to separate aggregates. I just want to make sure i'm doing the right thing. And when you say "it really depends on what you want to do with the model" - all im trying to do is the basic AddPost, UpdatePost, DeletePost, AddComment and DeleteComment at this stage - this demo is simplistic so i can understand the DDD decisions involved. "denormalized query for displaying a single post with it's comments": does this mean a way for the Post repo to return Posts and Comments together in an 'aggregated' fashion?

Comment: Yes it would. You could probably return a view model directly from your service/repo layer that has a post with it's associated comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is whether a comment has any meaning outside of the post aggregate. IMHO, there isn't any, so I think you shouldn't move the comment to its own aggregate.

Comment: Agreed. So what's the solution to getting the `Comment` instance in the controller example?

Comment: I think the Post entity should have a RemoveComment Method, which removes the comment with the given id from the comments collection.
Than you should do something like this:
Load the post entity,
call post.RemoveComment(commentId),
Update the post

Comment: Would a `RemoveComment` method on the `Post` entity be in preference to simply using the `Post`'s "Comments" collection's "Add" and "Remove" methods? And then have the Repo update the `Post`? Or is it more logical to do the 'removing' from the `Post`? Because if that's true then i'd want to enforce as much control declaratively as i can - and in this case perhaps have "Comments" as an Enumerable rather than a Collection so "Add" and "Remove" don't exist as options right?

Comment: That's what I usually do if I do have a child collection that's managed by the aggregate, yes.  The challenge will be that not all ORMs make that easy to do, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, it depends greatly on whether a comment has any meaning outside of a Post.  I tend to think that it does, for several reasons.  First, things other than posts can conceptually be commented upon in a normal blog engine (e.g. an image, a news item, another comment).  Second, as was also brought up, you often see widgets of just comments, which are independent of their posts.  I also think that this scenario makes the decisions you're agonizing over a bit more trivial.

That said, if you do choose to make them one aggregate, then remember that a repository will often load the entire aggregate when making queries, relying on mechanisms like caching and such to make that efficient.  So your scenario would be a query for a post, followed by a search of that post's comments for the 'right' comment to edit/delete/whatever.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion , comment should be part of Post Aggregate, but comment should be entity, bcoz two comment with the same answer is still two separate comment.

If you create comment as separate aggregate where comment is root then, comment will have store method that means any body can create comment but the basic idea is comment should not be created without its post.Comment is related with post.

If you think logically , Comment cannot be evolve it's own. That means when commented is created it should be part of post.

Comment: Totally agree. So how then do i lookup/traverse to a `Comment` from the Repo/Post aggregate?

Comment: Class Post{                                                      public List<Comment> Comments{get;set;}, You should load post from database along with all comments in infrastructure layer in repositories. how you load post whether from nhibernate or from Ef is totally on you. Please use factories to reconstituting the Post aggregate from database.

Comment: To delete comment from post , you should have method in Post like DeletComment(id), now if you delete 4 comments from post then you have restore the whole post aggregates in database after deletion